# peer.js / webrtc - how to setup a super simple data connection?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, peerjs

My situation is that I need to have a two directional signalling channel between two computers that reside on the same network. It is really only about sending 'pings' back and forth. Both computers can be seen as same privileged.

I was trying to use webrtc abstracted by peer.js to open a simple data channel. I'd like to use the same code on both clients as far as possible.

**Ideal solution would be:** two users can go to the website and get connected together automatically, without choosing an ID / remote ID to connect to.

I don't understand: is there the need of designating a caller/listener specifically or can both sides begin the connection? Can anyone point me out to the most simple implementation of such a connection? I'm using the free dev key for their server to run the brokering of the connections. Thanks!

Comment: check http://socket.io/blog/socket-io-p2p/#, haven't tried it myself but it sounds promising.

Answer (score 1):

With peer.js, you have to know the connection id of the peer you want to connect to. This means you need some server side logic to broker a connection.

If you just always want to connect the latest two incoming clients, you can simply start with 1 as id, try to construct the Peer, and while it fails, increment the id and try again. Then if you have succeeded with an odd number, do nothing, and when you have succeeded with an even number, open a connection to yourid - 1 and start using the connection:

```
// Use id prefix so we don't collide with other users on peer cloud server
let id_prefix = 'quarnos-';
let id = 0;
let peer = null;
let connection = null;

// Try to initialize peer using incrementing id
do {
  id++;
  peer = new Peer(id_prefix + id);
} while (!peer);

// When someone connects to us, save connection and log message
peer.on('connection', function(incoming_connection) {
  incoming_connection.on('data', function(data){
    if (!connection) {
      connection = incoming_connection;
      connection.send('connection established');
    }
    console.log(data);
    // Here you could put some timed connection.send() logic to make it go back and forth between peers, as requested in the OP
  });
});

// A peer with an even id tries to connect to the peer with id one lower (peer 2 connects to peer 1, etc.)
if (id % 2) {
  let connection = peer.connect(id_prefix + (id - 1));
  connection.on('open', function(){
    console.log('trying to establish connection to ' + id_prefix + (id - 1));
    connection.send('connection opened by ' + (id_prefix + id));
  });
}
```

This should print `trying to establish connection to quarnos-1` and `connection established` on peer 2 and `connection opened by quarnos-2` on peer 1.
Obviously it's not very robust and just a minimal example that shows a quick and dirty way how to connect two computers. You should really implement some server side logic that manages connections and maybe store the connection id in a cookie, so that you can reconnect to the same peer on page reload.

Comment: an example would be really helpful

Answer (score 1):

If you host your own PeerJS-server(which is very easy on heroku, there's a '**deploy to heroku**' button on their repo) you can get a list of all connected peers by using this.

`listAllPeers(function cb(list){...});`

It sends a list of all connected peers, you could write a randomizer to return an ID & connect those peers together. You could also populate a list onscreen & have the user select any one of them. The peer ids in this case are automatically generated by the server for you.